# Parsing Zimbra SOAP response with SimpleXML and xpath

Tags: php, xml, soap, xpath, zimbra

So, I'm using PHP to talk to a Zimbra SOAP server.  The response is in a `<soap:Envelope>` tag.  I'm having trouble parsing the XML response because of the namespace(s).

The XML looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header>
    <context xmlns="urn:zimbra">
      <change token="20333"/>
    </context>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateAccountResponse xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
      <account id="83ebf344-dc51-47ae-9a36-3eb24281d53e" name="iamtesting@example.com">
        <a n="zimbraId">83ebf344-dc51-47ae-9a36-3eb24281d53e</a>
        <a n="zimbraMailDeliveryAddress">iamtesting@example.com</a>
      </account>
    </CreateAccountResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I make a new `SimpleXMLElement` object:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
```

After Googling a bit, I found I need to register the namespace.  So I do that:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
```

Then I can get the `<soap:Body>` tag easily.

```
$body = $xml->xpath('//soap:Body');
```

But I can't get any elements after that (using xpath):

```
$CreateAccountResponse = $xml->xpath('//soap:Body/CreateAccountResponse');
```

This returns an empty array.  I can traverse the XML though, to get that element.

```
$CreateAccountResponse = $body[0]->CreateAccountResponse;
```

This works fine, but now I want to get the `<a>` tags, specifically the `zimbraId` one.  So I tried this:

```
$zimbraId = $CreateAccountResponse->account->xpath('a[@n=zimbraId]');
```

No luck, I get a blank array.  What's going on?  Why can't I use xpath to get elements (that don't start with `soap:`)?

How can I get the `<a>` tags based on their `n` attribute?

P.S. I'm aware that the `id` and `name` are also in the `<account>` tag's attributes, but there are a bunch more `<a>` tags that I want to get using the `n` attribute.

Note: I'm trying to improve the Zimbra library for my application for work.  The current code to get the `<a>` tags is as follows:

```
$zimbraId = strstr($data, "<a n=\"zimbraId\"");
$zimbraId = strstr($zimbraId, ">");
$zimbraId = substr($zimbraId, 1, strpos($zimbraId, "<") - 1);
```

Obviously, I want to remove this code (there's also some regexes (*shudder*) later on in the code), and use an XML parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements you want to retrieve have a namespace as well, namely `urn:zimbraAdmin`.

```
    <CreateAccountResponse xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
```

The xmlns attribute states the default namespace for any child elements, so the elements you are trying to retrieve actually have a namespace, even though no prefix is used (see [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) for some examples). If you specify a namespace prefix as you did for `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope` you should be fine.

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('zimbra', 'urn:zimbraAdmin');
$CreateAccountResponse = $xml->xpath('//soap:Body/zimbra:CreateAccountResponse');
```

Comment: Cool, thanks.  That did the trick.  Once I registered the `zimbra` namespace, it all worked (as long as I prefixed everything with `zimbra:`).  I used this xpath query this to get the element I want: `'//soap:Body/zimbra:CreateAccountResponse/zimbra:account/zimbra:a[@n="zimbraId"]'`.

Comment: I also realized I had to `registerXPathNamespace` on elements, if I saved it to a variable.  Such as `$x = $CreateAccountResponse[0]->account;`  I had to do `$x->registerXPathNamespace('zimbra', 'urn:zimbraAdmin');` to get it to work.  Then I could do `$x->xpath('zimbra:a[@n="zimbraId"]')`.

Comment: This post seems to collaborate that fact unfortunately: http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=443