# Getting XML values in PHP with namespace prefix

Tags: php, xml, namespaces

This is a follow-on question to this:
[Getting XML attributes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325821/getting-xml-attributes-in-php)

I'm struggling to get element values with a namespace prefix. See this example from here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppaidapplications/limit=10/genre=6014/xml

```
<im:image height="53">http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/114/Purple/v4/bc/0e/86/bc0e8619-5d48-1efe-2ac3-662696fb9a34/mzl.bimldzcn.53x53-50.png</im:image>          
<im:image height="75">http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/114/Purple/v4/bc/0e/86/bc0e8619-5d48-1efe-2ac3-662696fb9a34/mzl.bimldzcn.75x75-65.png</im:image>
```

If I try and reference the element using $e->im:image I get the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':'
```

$e->'im:image' gives me:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I've edited the question title which was misleading. It's actually element values with a namespace prefix (not attributes) that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using SimpleXML (as suggested by [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325821/getting-xml-attributes-in-php)) you have to use the [children()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method to fetch all child elements of a certain namespace, same with [attributes()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

e.g.

```
<?php
define('URI_RSS', 'http://itunes.apple.com/rss');
$feed = new SimpleXMLElement(getData());

foreach( $feed->entry as $entry ) {
    $attributes = $entry->id->attributes(URI_RSS);
    echo 'id[im:id]: ', $attributes['id'], "\n";

    $attributes = $entry->category->attributes(URI_RSS);
    echo 'category[im:id]: ', $attributes['id'], "\n";

    $imElements = $entry->children(URI_RSS);
    foreach( $imElements as $name=>$c ) {
        echo $name, '=', $c, "\n";
    }
}

function getData() {
    return <<< eot
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <feed xmlns:im="http://itunes.apple.com/rss" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="en">
        <id>someid</id><title>some title</title><updated>2012-09-10T02:12:06-07:00</updated><link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://link1"/><link rel="self" href="http://link12"/><icon>http://iconlink1</icon><author><name>some name</name><uri>http://uri</uri></author><rights>all rights wronged</rights>

            <entry>
                <updated>2012-09-10T02:12:06-07:00</updated>

                    <id im:id="123456789" im:bundleId="a.bundle.id">http://id</id>

                    <title>some title</title>

                    <summary>This is the summary.

A short text summarizing the complete article
</summary>

                    <im:name>imname</im:name>

                    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://alternate"/>

                    <im:contentType term="Application" label="Application"/>

                    <category im:id="7890" term="example" scheme="http://scheme" label="example"/>

                    <link title="Preview" rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://preview" im:assetType="preview"><im:duration>0</im:duration></link>

                    <im:artist href="http://artist">sample artist</im:artist>

                    <im:price amount="0.99000" currency="USD">$0.99</im:price>

                    <im:image height="53">http://1.png</im:image>

                    <im:image height="75">http://2.png</im:image>

                    <im:image height="100">http://3.png</im:image>

                    <rights>all rights wronged</rights>

                    <im:releaseDate label="August 28, 2012">2012-08-28T00:00:00-07:00</im:releaseDate>


                    <content type="html">content
                    content
                    content
</content>

            </entry>
        </feed>
eot;
}
```

prints

```
id[im:id]: 123456789
category[im:id]: 7890
name=imname
contentType=
artist=sample artist
price=$0.99
image=http://1.png
image=http://2.png
image=http://3.png
releaseDate=2012-08-28T00:00:00-07:00
```

Comment: Sorry - updated question to make it more accurate. It's the element values I'm interested in NOT the attributes.

Comment: OK. Clearly this works although I ended up using a simpler method (see my answer) but I'm going to tick yours off as it's more comprehensive.

Comment: it's the same method, `$entry->children(URI_RSS);`, I just defined `URI_RSS` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

-->[php domdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
-->[get Elements by tag name and namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php)

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it.

Answer is to specify the namespace.

E.g. see previous question and use:

```
$im = $e->children('http://itunes.apple.com/rss');
```